# what class or viewController is that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

sorry for this question, but i dont know where to search for it, or how to google it, because i dont have any idea how to search it.

with what class/viewController/API is such a "popup" built?

[alt text http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/1096/screenshot2010022814480.png](http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/1096/screenshot2010022814480.png)

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)